# How do I catch MySQL errors in a try catch block?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, try-catch

I am trying to execute a query on a MySQL database. I've put the execute command in a try catch block, but It still throws an exception when the query fails. How do I prevent this and simply catch the error?

```
Dim db_connection As String = my_connection_string
Dim MyConn As OdbcConnection  
MyConn = New OdbcConnection(db_connection)
Dim MyCommand As New OdbcCommand()
Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader = Nothing
MyCommand.Connection = MyConn
MyConn.Open()

query = "Alter table Table1 ADD COLUMN `col_2` VARCHAR(50) AFTER `col_1`"
MyCommand.CommandText = query
try
     myReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader()
catch ex as Exception
     output(ex.tostring)
end try
myReader.Close()
```

If the column already exists, it throws an error but if it does not, then everything is fine and the query gets executed and the program go on.

Comment: Which line is the exception occurring on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to catch an exception, you should catch the whole code of the query because, the connection can fail as well for instance.

```
Dim db_connection As String = my_connection_string
Dim MyConn As OdbcConnection  
Dim MyCommand As New OdbcCommand()

try
     MyConn = New OdbcConnection(db_connection)
     MyCommand.Connection = MyConn
     MyConn.Open()
     query = "Alter table Table1 ADD COLUMN `col_2` VARCHAR(50) AFTER `col_1`"
     MyCommand.CommandText = query
     MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
catch ex as Exception
     output(ex.tostring)
end try
```

EDIT:

```
Try
    Using connection As New OdbcConnection(my_connection_string)
        query = "Alter table Table1 ADD COLUMN `col_2` VARCHAR(50) AFTER `col_1`"
        Using command As New OdbcCommand(query, connection)
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using   
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

EDIT

```vb
Try
    'code here
Catch exception As OdbcException
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message)
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: I tried that, but the exception is still thrown. I think I need to catch the odbc connection error but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: I tried using "Catch ex as OdbcException" but it never reaches the Catch line of code. The exception is thrown at the execute line.

Comment: I tried the new edit and it still throws the Mysql exception at the command.ExecuteNonQuery line.

Comment: @user2721815 what is the exception message

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [42S12] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.6.14-log]Can't DROP 'updated_item'; check that column/key exists

Comment: In this case I am trying to drop an index using `alter table 'table1'  drop Index 'updated_item';` Once the index has been removed, it can't be removed again.

Comment: @user2721815 perhaps this `updated_item` has a constraint on it? For example you cant drop a foreign key like this

Comment: Well, it is no longer an index so I am trying to drop an index that no longer exists.

Comment: It works the first time through and it effectively drops the index like I need it to, but the second time through, it throws the exception because the index has already been dropped.

Comment: ok, so this is the normal behavior, does the code catch the exception or your application is terminated

Comment: the application is terminated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103750/discussion-between-meda-and-user2721815).